# Changing data for a specific time period throughout a year to zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have solar performance data at 5-second intervals which spans a full year. The issues is data is reflecting performance at night. I would like to change these values all to zero.

I have tried using:

`data.between_time('00:00:00','06:11:00')['SYSTEM MPPT PV Power [W]']) = 0`

and

`data.between_time('17:00:00','23:59:55')['SYSTEM MPPT PV Power [W]']) = 0`

and

`data.at_time('00:00:00')['SYSTEM MPPT PV Power [W]']) = 0`

seeing that these are the periods that should have no perfomance.

However, this does not allow me to make an assignment to the column that is reflecting the performance.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps `data.loc[data['SYSTEM MPPT PV Power [W]'].between_time('00:00:00','06:11:00'), 'SYSTEM MPPT PV Power [W]'] = 0`

Comment: the problem with this is the index must be datetimeIndex. Thanks Alexander

Comment: You didn’t provide any sample data, so it is difficult to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.DataFrame.between_times](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) returns the rows between the times (assuming that the dataframe has a `datetimeindex`), does not select them. So assignment operator does not work.

Assuming that your dataframe has a `datetimeindex` (it should have, since you are using `between_times`) you can use `between_times` to find the indexes at which you want to have 0, and do the assignment in the following line:

```
zeroidx = data.between_time('00:00:00','06:11:00').index.\
         append([data.between_time('17:00:00','23:59:55').index, \
         data.at_time('00:00:00').index])

data.loc[zeroidx, 'SYSTEM MPPT PV Power [W]'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, Valentino. There seems to be one other issue. Whenever I save the data there seem to be some duplicates.

Comment: This code does not create any duplicate. You should check your original data. If there are duplicate in the original dataframe, they of course will be still there.